# caml query to filter by year not working

Tags: caml-query

I would like to filter a list based on the year as parameter. For e.x. if i use 2014, all items from 1/1/2014 to 31/12/2014 should appear and also i am filtering on region. For the caml query below, if there is an item which was entered on 1/1/2014, it does not show up.Any idea why...

```
<Query>
  <Where>
  <And>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Region' />
        <Value Type='Lookup'>A1.1</Value>
     </Eq>
     <And>
        <Geq>
           <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />
           <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>2014-01-01</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Leq>
           <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />
           <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>2014-12-31</Value>
        </Leq>
     </And>
  </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='DueDate' Ascending='False' />
 </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the ISO 8601 DateTime format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
```

Even if you aren't comparing against the time value, the ISO 8601 format is still expected.

Given `DateTime dueDate` You can use:

```
<Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>dueDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")</Value>
```

Or the [`SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx):

```
<Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dueDate)</Value>
```

See [SharePoint 2010 Working with Dates in CAML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414414/SharePoint-2010-Working-with-Dates-in-CAML)

Comment: Like this solutions but how can i offset the dates using any of these methods?