# CAML query not working with dates no idea why

Tags: caml

I have startdate as 18/12/2014 and enddate as 22/12/2014 
But when trying to use the below query it doesn't work

```
 <Where>
  <Or>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='StartDate' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>
           <Today Offset='7' />
        </Value>
     </Geq>
     <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>
           <Today Offset='-7' />
        </Value>
     </Leq>
  </Or>
```

Thanks in advance.
I did wrap a `<Query></Query>` around it.
Thanks I Advance

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/caml-query-to-filter-by-year-not-working

Comment: Thanks for that but i still need the OffSet.How can i deduct the days from Today using either of the methods

Comment: I saw this on SPServices forum as well. The correct attribute to use is OffsetDays - regardless of what the MS docs have. 
To me, it looks like the values of Geq and Leq are reversed.  The above is trying to get all items where the start date is greater than 7 days from today --OR-- the end date is Less than 7 days ago.  Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using 'OffsetDays' instead of 'Offset'?

```
<Today OffsetDays='-7'/>
```

Comment: How does OffsetDays differ from Offset? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460496%28v=office.15%29.aspx) states that the only attribute for `<Today>` is `Offset`.

Comment: Maybe the documentation is wrong. I can't find any proof of that - but this site suggests that at one time there were some comments regarding it on MSDN. [TechMotley](http://techmotley.com/2012/01/27/correct-offset-for-today-in-caml-queries)

Comment: Very peculiar.  Btw, you might want to redo that link, the closing > got added to the end of the url.

Comment: Fixed the link, thanks for the heads up - sorry about that.

Comment: Hi wjeris, Im using this on a sharepoint 2010 so is it 'OffsetDays' or 'Offset'?

Comment: After writing a js to output a date and deduct days.Tried the OffsetDays and it started working arg!!! Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried building the CAML Query like this?

This gives you a date offset of 7 days.

```
<Where>
  <Or>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='Created' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>[18/12/2014 08:16:33 AM+7Day(s)]</Value>
     </Geq>
     <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='Created' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>[18/12/2014 08:16:57 AM-7Day(s)]</Value>
     </Leq>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

Comment: Thanks Vince Im doing this via script and trying to find a way i can deduct the time before using it as i need it in ISO format

Comment: Can you post the script your using?